# assert_raises() from nose tools doesn't really work

Tags: python, python-2.7, nosetests

Ok, here is the problem: in [exercise 49](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex49.html) of "Learn Python the Hard Way" by Zed Shaw, we need to test a couple of exceptions with `assert_raises()`. Here is the function, that I'm testing and if omitting the `assert_raises()` part, it passes the test:

```
def parse_verb(word_list):
    skip(word_list, 'stop')

    if peek(word_list) == 'verb':
        return match(word_list, 'verb')
    else:
        raise ParserError("Expected a verb next.")
```

Here is the test function and the infamous `assert_raises()` line:

```
def parse_verb_test():
    vrb_list = [('of', 'stop'), ('from', 'stop'), ('go', 'verb'), ('north', 'direction')]
    assert_equal(parse_verb(vrb_list), ('go', 'verb'))
    assert_equal(vrb_list, [('north', 'direction')])
    assert_raises(ParserError, parse_verb, vrb_list)
```

And it gives me the following output:

```
.........E...
======================================================================
ERROR: tests.parser_tests.parse_verb_test
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/Users/vsevolod/Repositories/ex48/tests/parser_tests.py", line 20, in parse_verb_test
    assert_raises(ParserError, parse_verb, vrb_list)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 471, in assertRaises
    callableObj(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/vsevolod/Repositories/ex48/ex48/parser.py", line 40, in parse_verb
    raise ParserError("Expected a verb next.")
TypeError: object.__new__() takes no parameters

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 13 tests in 0.042s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I also tried getting rid of the `assert_raises()` line and using the `@raises(ParserError)` before the function. It also didn't quite work and resulted in the same output.

Creating a separate test like this helped to get rid of the error:

```
def parse_verb_fail():
    fail_list = [('north', 'direction'), ('go', 'verb')]
    assert_raises(ParserError, parse_verb, fail_list)
```

But now the test is simply ignored.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The first thing I usually recommend when debugging ones tests is that you should only have 1 assert per test. Why? If one of the three (in your case) fail the others won't run so what you've actually created is a dependency between asserts. I think if you refactor your tests this will resolve it self.

Comment: Moving `assert_raises()` to the separate `verb_parser_fail` test did help to get rid of the error, but for now it just ignores the test. It still outputs that 13 tests has been passed and etc and commenting the test doesn't reduce that number.

Comment: It looks like the exception you're getting is not the one you're expecting (a `TypeError` rather than a `ParseError`). Is your `ParserError` type defined correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your problem is that `ParserError` doesn't have a constructor that takes a string (or `ParserError` doesn't extend from `Exception` and is trying to pass a string to the base object's init method...).  So when you try and create `ParserError` you are getting a `TypeError` and not a `ParserError`.  Since your `assert_raises()` wasn't expecting a `TypeError` it doesn't catch it.

EDIT:

Looking at the example code you linked to and playing around.  Are you sure you have...

```
class ParserError(Exception): pass
```

...and not...

```
class ParserError(object): pass
```

Comment: Yes! I tried changing it to `TypeError` in the original test and it passed without problems. Then I just change the parent of `ParserError` to `Exception` and it worked too. Thank you!

Comment: This part with `Exception` being the parent of `ParserError` is even **marked red** in the code snippet given by Zed Shaw, I don't know how I've missed it.

Comment: Dammit, Pace beat me to it.  Generally, @VsevolodGlumov, exceptions are (often indirect) subclasses of Exception.  Python doesn't enforce an exception hierarchy ("consenting adults"), but pretty much all code out there adheres to it.

Answer (score 0):

Zed Shaw's Learn Python the Hard Way is still a great resource, so perhaps my contribution could be helpful.

The reason the parse_verb_fail function is ignored is that nose test functions must have "test_" in the name, or as the [documentation](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing_tests.html) says more fully:

> Any function or class that matches the configured testMatch regular expression ((?:^|[\b_\.-])[Tt]est by default – that is, has test or Test at a word boundary or following a - or _) and lives in a module that also matches that expression will be run as a test.

Here's my solution that worked:

```
def test_parse_errors():
    subject_fail_list = [('stop', 'the'), ('direction', 'north')]
    assert_raises(parser.ParseError, parser.parse_subject, subject_fail_list)
```

nose will run this test and it will pass. Changing one of the tuples to ('noun', 'john') will cause the test to fail, since parse_subject is looking for 'noun'.